# How extract strings in csv-file between two types of strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have csv-file with too many trash. How to extract strings in csv-file between two types of strings?

My file
[image: There is my csv-file]

Expected output:

[image: There is what i want to extract from file]

How i can extract LE-line, all Ht-lines until Id!=Ev?

Comment: Please add your sample/expected data as text, not images.

Comment: Do you need my csv-file or just the copied part of the document?

Comment: Just copy the relevant part. For now, your expected output doesn't seem to relate to what you show.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xVf3VdgeTgd1jsXNHPyn3mJk0IDhXxbylslwA7i1ouI/edit?usp=sharing) There is my expected result

Comment: Have you tried reading in the data using pandas' read_csv function?